# How to set compiler specific standard headers #include paths?

Tags: c, libraries, cross-compilation, compiler, header-file

What is a smart way to tell two compilers to look for their `#include` headers?

Running on a standard Linux 86x64 system, my standard compiler is `gcc` (currently v9.3). 
Now I'd like to compile some things with `tcc` and have it installed in a local users directory.

How could I tell `tcc` where to look for the `#include`path?
I expect it to be at

- `/home/user/lib/tcc/v0.9/include` or
- `/home/user/lib/tcc/v0.9/lib/tcc/include`

Comment: Let `cmake` do this for you?

Comment: I'd like to get along without `cmake`. Can you layout how it does it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How could I tell tcc where to look for the `#include` path?

Use the `-I` option, just as with gcc or clang:

From `man tcc`:

> ```
>   -Idir
>       Specify an additional include path. Include paths are searched in the order they are specified.
>
>       System include paths are always searched after. The default system include paths are: /usr/local/include, /usr/include
>        and PREFIX/lib/tcc/include. (PREFIX is usually /usr or /usr/local).
> ```

I don't believe that tcc makes any distinction between the `<...>` and `"..."` include forms.

Also, as noted in `man tcc`, you can use `tcc -vv` to show you the default paths. On my system, this shows:

```
tcc version 0.9.27 (x86_64 Linux)
install: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/tcc
include:
  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/tcc/include
  /usr/local/include/x86_64-linux-gnu
  /usr/local/include
  /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu
  /usr/include
libraries:
  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
  /usr/lib
  /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
  /lib
  /usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
  /usr/local/lib
libtcc1:
  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/tcc/libtcc1.a
crt:
  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
elfinterp:
  /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
```